# How to integration paypal module in iphone application using titanium?

Tags: titanium

I am implementing one iphone application using titanium tool.

In this application I want to integrate paypal module so user can loging with paypal userid and password and then can purchase some product or etc.

How to do using Titanium tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a use full link for you. [PayPal & Titanium](http://thenativeadvantage.com/2010/10/paypal-titanium/)

Comment: Thanks I am looking for like this

Answer (score 0):

Check out Titanium + Commerce Mobile Payment Library:
http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titaniumcommerce/
Or the titanium plus program:
http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titaniumplus/